# How to quickly print data in a Qt model for debugging?

Tags: python, qt, debugging, model-view-controller

Sometimes, I'd find it useful to dump some data from a Qt model (inheriting from `QAbstractItemModel`) to the console, to get a rough idea of what I'm dealing with, while debugging. The sort of thing you'd do with objects implementing `__repr__`. It would use the data in the display role.

Is there a quick way to do something like that? If there isn't, am I missing a point somewhere? How else would you quickly check what data a model contains, without going through the steps of implementing a view, widget, etc, and relaunching the GUI tool? How would you debug models/data in the Qt model/view framework?

I know I'm not an expert in Qt and there might be obvious contradictions in my question, but this is something I have yet to find a satisfying answer to, despite having searched the topic multiple times. Thank you for any help you're able to provide.

Comment: One way I could see to do this is to use the `data` method and some logic to iterate through all the indices, as well as logic to format things in a somewhat readable way before printing. But is there something equivalent to this already implemented in Qt?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough implementation in python of the type of functionality I was looking for. It works with `Qt.py`, with `model` being of a class inheriting from `QAbstractItemModel`:

```py
from Qt import QtCore

def print_model_data(model, parent=None, level=0, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
    parent = parent or QtCore.QModelIndex()
    for r in range(model.rowCount(parent)):
        for c in range(model.columnCount(parent)):
            index = model.index(r, c, parent)
            if index is None:
                continue

            print("    " * level + str(index.data(role)))
            print_model_data(model, index, level+1)
```

Usage:

```py
>>> print_model_data(model)
root_0
   root_0_elem_0
   root_0_elem_1
root_1
   root_1_elem_0
```

This might not cover all use cases yet, I'll update my answer if needed.